# Creating a Fake DOM to test in a JavaScript test suite

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, dom

### The problem

> - TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

### The question

I am using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) to handle my JavaScript's unit test and it brings embedded [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), which should to handle the DOM-related subjects.

This is my fragment of test:
    jest.dontMock ('fs');

```
var markup = require ('fs')
  .readFileSync(__dirname + '/markup/index.html')
  .toString();

describe ('my app', function () {
  it ('should initialize adding <h1> to the DOM', function () {
    document.documentElement.innerHtml = markup;

    app.start();

    expect(app.DOM).toEqual('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
  });
});
```

The implementation of `.start()` has within:

```
document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'Hello world';
```

When running the library in browser, it works well. But when testing via CLI, it don't.

### Diagnostics

Basically, I tried the following:

```
 it ('should initialize adding <h1> to the DOM', function () {
    document.documentElement.innerHtml = markup;

    console.log(document.querySelector('h1'));

    // [...]
  });
```

And the `console.log()` outputs '`null`' — seems like the markup I created isn't being added to the "DOM" that jsdom created.

This is the content of `/markup/index.html`, also the same as `markup` variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Linguisticjs Markup Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bonjour le monde !</h1>
  <h3>Comment ça va ?</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo. This is wrong:

```
document.documentElement.innerHtml
```

It should be `innerHTML`. The way you are doing it is creating a field named `innerHtml` but does not have for effect to create DOM nodes.

Comment: Man, I can't believe. Hours trying to figure out what's the problem and then... LOL. Thank you anyway!